# Problem on conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

> A parcel is launched at speed of $3.0\; \mathrm{ms}^{-1}$ up a rough
>   plane inclined at an angle of $35^o$ above the horizontal. The
>   coefficient of kinetic friction between the parcel and the plane is $0.30$.
>
> Determine the maximum distance travelled by the parcel up the plane.

My attempt
$$ (1/2)mv^2 = 0.3\times 9.81\times \cos15^o\times s\times\cos180^o +9.81\times\sin35^o $$
This yields $s$ equals $1.4$.
But the answer given is $0.560$.

I recheck my calculation and notice that I'll get $s = 0.560$ if the work done against friction is positive. But we all know work done against friction is negative due to $\cos180^o$. Is the answer wrong?

Comment: Conservation requires that the final KE = initial KE + the work done on the mass.  In this case the final KE is zero, and the work done (on the mass) by gravity and friction are both negative.  Taken to the other side of the equation, both are positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the right sequence of statements about conversation of energy:

**Work-energy theorem**
$$A = K_2 - K_1$$
In the left part of this equation one can see the summary work done by all the forces applied to the body. There are different types of forces:

1. Potential: $\qquad A_{potential} = \text{П}_1 - \text{П}_2 $
2. Dissipative:      $\,A_{dissipative} < 0$
3. Gyroscopical:    $\ \ A_{gyroscopical} = 0$

You have 3 forces acting on body in your problem: gyroscopical normal reaction force (it is perpendicular to displacement of the body); potential force of gravity; dissipative force of friction. So:
$$ A_{potential} + A_{dissipative} + A_{gyroscopical} = A_{gravity} + A_{friction}$$
To calculate $A_{gravity}$ one can do this: $A_{gravity} = \text{П}_1 - \text{П}_2 = - mgh$, where $h$ is the positive magnitude of displacement of body in vertical direction. We derive:
$$ A_{friction} - mgh = K_2 - K_1$$
If body stops at the end, we should assume $K_2 = 0$:
$$ A_{friction} - mgh = - K_1$$
$$ A_{friction} = mgh - K_1$$
At this step it is useful to remember: $ A_{friction}$ is negative! You can imagine process like this: body has kinetic energy on the start, but then losts it in two ways - gravitional work and work of friction forces:
$$ K_1 = mgh + (- A_{friction}) $$
One more time: both $mgh$ and $- A_{friction}$ are positive in this equation!

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you @goroshek.

Comment: @arthur, please consider accept this answer if it was helpful for you. You may invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//physics.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Physics way of saying thank you.